# How to Apply a color to excel cell using Qt?

Tags: c++, excel, qt, automation, qaxobject

I am new to Qt . I have written a program to read and write datas from excel file.

```
    void Excel::Color(const QString& Sheet_Name,const QString& cell,const QString& color_Name) { 
  QAxObject* Worksheet = activeWorkbook->querySubObject("WorkSheets(const QString&)",Sheet_Name); 
  QAxObject* Cell_Range = Worksheet->querySubObject("Range(const QString&)",cell ); 
}
```

Now i need to apply color to particular cell. Is there any posibility to achieve this ?

Comment: void Excel::Color(const QString& Sheet_Name,const QString& cell,const QString& color_Name)
{
 QAxObject* Worksheet = activeWorkbook->querySubObject("WorkSheets(const QString&)",Sheet_Name);
 QAxObject* Cell_Range = Worksheet->querySubObject("Range(const QString&)",cell );
} !! Now i need to set particular color to a cell in the sheet which is specified in sheet_Name. !! how can i set the color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a [delphi](/questions/tagged/delphi) enthusiast, I did office automation in the past. I don't feel very comfortable with Qt but I have Qt Creator 2.4.0 installed on my box with the latest Qt framework: It's very promising.

Here is a VBA snippet more relevant to Cell coloring,

```
Cells(1, “D”).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 255)
Cells(1, “D”).Borders.Weight = xlThick
Cells(1, “D”).Borders.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
```

You can also head to this interesting [thread](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/forums/viewthread/1871) related to harnessing Excel file with QAxWidget.

**Edit:**

The OP finally end up founding an appropriate Qt solution as follows:

```
QAxObject* Interior = currentCell->querySubObject("Interior"); 
Interior->setProperty("ColorIndex",Index_val);
```

Comment: I want it to be with Qt properties . so how can i do ? can you explain it clearly ?

Comment: Try something similar to Cell_Range->setProperty("Value", QVariant(1234));

Comment: QAxObject* Interior = currentCell->querySubObject("Interior");   Interior->setProperty("ColorIndex",Index_val);                      And It works fine!!!! Thanks menjaraz !!

Comment: You are welcome. Don't forget to study the [Excel Object Model Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb149081%28v=office.12%29.aspx) to go further. I will edit accordingly the answer so that it can serve readily any visitor. If feel that my attempt to answer was helpfull you can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

How to get `currentCell`  object:

```
  QAxObject* Interior = currentCell->querySubObject("Interior"); 
  Interior->setProperty("ColorIndex",Index_val);
```